# How do I call on an array id within a multidimentional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key

The array I have looks like this:

```
$items = array();
$items["GB225"] = array (
    "name" => "AAA",
    "img" => "aaa.jpg",
    "includes" => array(
         $things[08] = array (
              "name" => "xxx",
              "text" => "xxxx xx xxxx x x  x xxx x x"
         );
         $things[77] = array (
              "name" => "yyy",
              "text" => "yyyyyy yy yyyyyy y yy yyyyy"
         ) ;
         $things[42] = array (
              "name" => "zzz",
              "text" =>"zz zzzz zzz z z zzz z"
         );
    );
);
```

What I need get is the ID and names for each of the second array elements (I'll need xxx with ID = 08, yyy with ID = 77, zzz with ID = 42) using PHP preferably.

My best guess so far has been

```
foreach ($items["includes"] as $thing_id => $thing) { 
     echo $thing["name"];
     echo $thing_id;
};
```

but this only gives me ID's 0, 1, and 2 associated with the "name".

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: change `$things[08] = array` to `8 => array` (ad so on)

Comment: By not removing the keys when you store them in that array (your array example does not compile, perhaps provide a `var_dump` of the _actual_ array).

Comment: The $things arrays are part of a larger, separate $things array with many more $things elements not listed. In the $items array, I did not actually define the $things array as is shown (poor communication, my mistake) but they are instead defined in a previously listed $things array and appear in the $items array only as $things[08], $things[77], $things[42].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is $things variable in your script ? This variable does not seem to be initialized.

Your code should look like

```
<?php
$items["GB225"] = array (
    "name" => "AAA",
    "img" => "aaa.jpg",
    "includes" => array(
        8 => array (
              "name" => "xxx",
              "text" => "xxxx xx xxxx x x  x xxx x x"
         ),
         77 => array (
              "name" => "yyy",
              "text" => "yyyyyy yy yyyyyy y yy yyyyy"
         ),
         42 => array (
             "name" => "zzz",
              "text" =>"zz zzzz zzz z z zzz z"
         )
    )
);

foreach ($items['GB225']["includes"] as $thing_id => $thing) { 
    echo $thing["name"];
     echo $thing_id;
}
```

Look here for a demo https://eval.in/55194

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code should look like:

```
<?php
$items = array();
$items["GB225"] = array (
    "name" => "AAA",
    "img" => "aaa.jpg",
    "includes" => array(
         8 => array (
              "name" => "xxx",
              "text" => "xxxx xx xxxx x x  x xxx x x"
         ),
         77 => array (
              "name" => "yyy",
              "text" => "yyyyyy yy yyyyyy y yy yyyyy"
         ),
         42 => array (
              "name" => "zzz",
              "text" =>"zz zzzz zzz z z zzz z"
         )
    )
);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($items);
```

Method 1:

```
foreach ($items as $key => $val) {
  foreach ($val as $key => $anArr) {
    if ($key == "includes")  {
      foreach ($anArr as $key => $val) {
        echo $key . " : " . $anArr[$key]['name'];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Method 2:

```
foreach ($items['GB225']["includes"] as $thing_id => $thing) { 
  echo $thing["name"];
  echo $thing_id;
}
```